# Is it good practice to replace short code that yields a boolean for use in conditionals with a function

Tags: javascript

I have on several lines of code a conditional like this:

```
if ( i < DEVICES ) { .... some code
```

This code is repeated several times in my code, 15 times to be exact. 
The thing is that since this is repeated I created a function that replaces the validation:

```
function isDevice(i) {return i < DEVICES; }
```

And replaced all my conditionals with the function:

```
if ( isDevice(i) ) { ... some code
```

Now I am thinking, even though the code is repeated several times, is it really worth using the function? I am asking because it's more lines of code that I am using to abstract something that is repeated 15 times, but is a very simple validation.

Comment: If you have code that's doing the same thing 15 times, switch to using an array and a `forEach` loop.

Comment: There's probably another solution. It's rare to have to check something so many times

Comment: Whatever works for you is fine. Your question is opinion-based and therefore off-topic

Comment: Number of lines is not as important as readability. I have not idea what `i < DEVICES` means, but `isDevice(i)` is quite clear.

Comment: What's your definition of "best"? This isn't really a question that has an objective answer.

Comment: Using a function is more understandable and it will be easier for someone that has to read your code after years, stick to that.

Comment: @sphanley, for best I mean, code readability, performance, best practices, etc, the code is done in d3.js

Comment: @SamuilPetrov, Thank You, The only one that answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @str, **readability is king**. If your program is of any use, it will spend a lot more time being maintained than being developed. So, when in doubt, always code for a future you (or a future colleague) that will have no idea of what you were thinking when you originally wrote the code.

Since `i < DEVICES-1` is less readable than `isDevice(i)`, I would vote for using the function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. If you had to change something about that condition (e.g. you made a mistake and it has to be

```
i < DEVICES-1
```

or something like that.

You don't have to change it 15 times, but only once.

Comment: IMHO the number of times you repeat that check isn't important at all (for such simple condition!) Much more important is that a function has a (descriptive) name while raw condition has not (and in this case it's not self-explicative) Is `device.isAvailable() && device.isReady()` much better than `isAvailableAndReady(device)`? We might discuss but for sure I don't want to see (even once) `device.address == undefined && device.status != 'busy'`

Comment: In OP's case the point is that his condition is obscure and variables are poorly named. If it was `deviceIndex < MAXIMUM_DEVICE_INDEX` then we might have less desire to extract a function `IsValidIndexForDevice(i)` for that-